# value error :setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, regression, valueerror

my code for `linear regression` with 3 features . i had tried to execute in terminal . i got the following error

> value error:setting an array with a sequence

```
import tensorflow as tf
INPUT_XOR=[[1,72,50,33.6],[1,66,31,26.6],[1,64,32,23.3],
[1,66,21,28.1],[1,40,33,43.1],[1,74,30,25.6],[1,50,26,31.0],
[1,0,29,35.3],[1,70,53,30.5],[96,54,0]]
OUTPUT_XOR=[[148],[85],[183],[89],[137],[116],[78],[115],[197],[125]]
n_nodes_hl1=10
n_nodes_hl2=1
batch_size=100
x=tf.placeholder('float',[10,4])
y=tf.placeholder('float',[10,1])


def train_neural_network(x):
    hidden_1_layer=
  {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([4,n_nodes_hl1],-1.0,1.0)),
        'biases':tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_nodes_hl1]))}
    output_layer=
  {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n_nodes_hl1,n_nodes_hl2], 
-1.0,1.0)),
        'biases':tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_nodes_hl2]))}
l1=tf.add(tf.matmul(x,hidden_1_layer['weights']),hidden_1_layer['biase
s'])
l1=tf.nn.relu(l1)
output=tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,output_layer['weights']),output_layer['biases'])
output=tf.sigmoid(output)
prediction=output
cost=tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(prediction,y))
optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)
hm_epochs=10000
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init_op=tf.global_variables_initializer()           
    sess.run(init_op)
    for epoch in range(100001):
        epoch_loss=0
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x:INPUT_XOR, y:OUTPUT_XOR})
        if epoch%10000==0:
            c=sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x:INPUT_XOR, y:OUTPUT_XOR})
            #epoch_loss+=c
            print('Epoch:', epoch, 'completed out of ',hm_epochs 
,'cost', c)
            print('_'*80)
            for element in sess.run(prediction, feed_dict=
  {x:INPUT_XOR, y:OUTPUT_XOR}):
                print('  ', element)
    correct=tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1),tf.argmax(y,1))
    accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct,'float'))
    print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:INPUT_XOR, y:OUTPUT_XOR}))





 train_neural_network(x)
```

output:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "", line 19, in train_neural_network
>     File "/home/vj/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-
>      packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)
>     File "/home/vj/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-
>      packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1093, in _run
>       np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
>     File "/home/vj/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-
>      packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
>       return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
>   ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

please help me to sort out this error

Answer (score 0):

The last row of the `INPUT_XOR` matrix has three elements instead of four. Try this code:

```
INPUT_XOR = [[1,72,50,33.6], [1,66,31,26.6], [1,64,32,23.3], [1,66,21,28.1], [1,40,33,43.1], [1,74,30,25.6], [1,50,26,31.0], [1,0,29,35.3], [1,70,53,30.5], [96,54,0,0.0]]
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Matthew. I forget to add one element to that . I will try this one and hope this will work for me